# Как назвать человека, работающего в другую смену?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Как назвать человека, работающего в другую смену и собирающегося тебя сменить? "Сменщик" не звучит складно.

Answer (score 2):

По отношению к первому работающему это именно "(его) **сменщик**". Есть множество литературных примеров, которые находятся через гугл-книги по запросу "мой сменщик".

Answer (score 1):

Это называется именно "сменщик".